# Obtener la extensión de una imagen subida a mi backend a través de Postman

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, api, backend

Estoy atascado con un problema, al subir una imagen por postman a mi backend me salta un error y no puedo continuar, ya que he mirado diferentes webs y no he podido conseguir solucionarlo. El error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.
```

Lo que quiero hacer es usar '.split()' para separar el nombre de la imagen en nombre y formato, como: png, jpg, jpeg, etc.

La funcion en cuestión es la siguiente:

```javascript
function uploadImage(req, res) {
  var userId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.files.image);
  if (req.files) {
    var file_path = req.files.image.path;
    console.log(file_path);

    var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
    console.log(file_split);

    var file_name = file_split[2];
    console.log(file_name);

    var ext_split = file_name.split('\.'); // <-- Aquí se encuentra el problema
    console.log(ext_split);

    var file_ext = ext_split[1];
    console.log(file_ext);
  }
}
```

Error obtenido:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
  at uploadImage (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/controllers/user.js:186:35)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at next (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
  at Form.<anonymous> (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/connect-multiparty/index.js:114:7)
  at Form.emit (events.js:327:22)
  at /Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:610:12
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Aquí un log de lo que sucede en la función

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
La conexión a la base de datos Codeqlick se ha realizado correctamente!
Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:3800
{
  fieldName: 'image',
  originalFilename: 'Alvise Feliu.png',
  path: 'uploads/users/m1dh2A-Y1qG5hOlK7rq_UlAp.png',
  headers: {
    'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="image"; filename="Alvise Feliu.png"',
    'content-type': 'image/png'
  },
  size: 22059,
  name: 'Alvise Feliu.png',
  type: 'image/png'
}
uploads/users/m1dh2A-Y1qG5hOlK7rq_UlAp.png
[ 'uploads/users/m1dh2A-Y1qG5hOlK7rq_UlAp.png' ]
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
  at uploadImage (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/controllers/user.js:187:35)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at next (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
  at Form.<anonymous> (/Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/connect-multiparty/index.js:114:7)
  at Form.emit (events.js:327:22)
  at /Users/AlviseFeliu/Desktop/Codeqlick/api/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:610:12
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En tu código hay varios `.split()`, ¿cuál de ellos es el que está tronando el código? Adicionalmente, ¿podrías compartir el contenido de `req.files` y/o `req.files.image`? parece obvio que está entrando al if pero quiero asegurarme del contenido que está llegando.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc ya he compartido el contenido para que me podais ayudar!

Comment: Ví tu actualización, parece que sí estás obteniendo información. Lo que te quiero pedir nuevamente es un `console.log(req.files.image)` para poder ver el string del que estás tratando de sacar la información. Adicionalmente, escapar el punto está de más, puedes hacerlo como `ext_split = file_name.split('.')` y seguiría funcionando.

Comment: Ya he adjuntado la documentación adicional! @ricardo-dlc

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece estar en la forma en la que estás haciendo el split del path. Según tus logs el string es algo como `'uploads/users/m1dh2A-Y1qG5hOlK7rq_UlAp.png'`, con diagonales normales `/` pero en tu código usas la diagonal invertida `\` para hacer el split, esto causa que en lugar de obtener un arreglo parecido a este: `['uploads', 'users', 'm1dh2A-Y1qG5hOlK7rq_UlAp.png']` obtengas en su lugar un arreglo con un solo elemento: `['uploads/users/m1dh2A-Y1qG5hOlK7rq_UlAp.png']` y al hacer esta asignación `file_name = file_split[2];` obtienes un `undefined` puesto que la posición 2 no existe (solo existe un elemento con índice 0).

Lo correcto entonces es que utilices la diagonal normal `/` para hacer el split, lo que nos dará como resultado el arreglo con los tres elementos antes mencionados y después puedes proceder a hacer las demás operaciones.

Adicionalmente, como ya te había mencionado en los comentarios, escapar el punto está de más, puedes usar el punto directamente y tu código seguirá funcionando.

```js
const req = {};
req.files = {};
req.files.image = {
  fieldName: 'image',
  originalFilename: 'Alvise Feliu.png',
  path: 'uploads/users/m1dh2A-Y1qG5hOlK7rq_UlAp.png',
  headers: {
    'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="image"; filename="Alvise Feliu.png"',
    'content-type': 'image/png'
  },
  size: 22059,
  name: 'Alvise Feliu.png',
  type: 'image/png'
}

function uploadImage(req, res) {
  // ...

  if (req.files) {
    const file_path = req.files.image.path;
    console.log('Path:', file_path);

    const file_split = file_path.split('/');
    console.log('Path parts:', file_split);

    // const file_name = file_split.slice(-1)[0]; // Lo mismo que:
    const file_name = file_split[2];
    console.log('Filename:', file_name);

    // const file_ext = file_name.split('.').slice(-1)[0]; // Lo mismo que:
    const file_ext = file_name.split('.')[1];
    console.log('File extension:', file_ext);
  }

  // ...
}

uploadImage(req);
```

Incluso, puedes evitar crear una variable intermediaria para extraer la extensión del archivo puesto que nunca más la vuelves a usar por lo que resulta mejor trabajar con el nombre directamente.